# My Gizmo is stuck in one place

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, gizmo

I am a little new to Blender's controls, but I learned the basics of 3D Modeling in Maya. My gizmo suddenly stopped automatically moving to the faces I was selecting while I was in the middle of modeling, and the gizmo was just stuck in one place. I believe I may have accidentally unchecked some option when messing with the grid visibility options or any of the tabs in the same area of the screen. Can anyone help me with this problem? I am using Blender 2.8 through Steam.[image]

Answer (score 2):

YOu probably change from individual origins to 3D Cursor

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thank you!